# how to display only last six words

Tags: python, html, django

so I want to display only last six words and truncate the first part.

```
{% for each_season in season %}

<a href="{% url 'season_detail' slug=each_season.slug %}">{{each_season|something}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

is there anything i can put into |something to achieve this goal?

Comment: Do you need Django slice https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#slice

Comment: @Keatinge: that will display the last six *characters*.

Comment: @rosababy: how exactly do you want to truncate the first part?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem say its theOfficeSeason1. I want to display season1 only

Comment: @rosababy: but these are the last six characters, not the last six words?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the last six of the word theOFficeseason1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [**slice**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter

**Ex:**

```
{% for each_season in season %}
    <a href="{% url 'season_detail' slug=each_season.slug %}">{{each_season|slice:"-6:"}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried but this doesn't work, it outputs literally {{each_season|slice:"-6:"}}